# Transactional emails not being received by client

Tags: email, order-email

A client has reported that they are not receiving sales emails. If I add my own email address as a BCC into the sales email, I receive it. I have run into similar issues in the past whereby emails generated by website abc.com are not received by email address @abc.com, but are received by emails with other domains.

I realise this is probably a server issue rather than magento, but I wondered if anyone else has had the same issue and if there is an easy way to resolve it?

Comment: if you're running your own mail server, better ask on serverfault.SE or something, if you're hosting it somewhere and using a provider, talk to them, there's an issue on their side. This can be somewhat complex and the solution to this is everything but easy or distinct